# Can't establish a relationship between objects in different contexts when using a background context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to insert an `NSManagedObject` through a background context and I'm getting this error:

```
Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'location' between objects in different contexts (source = <Image: 0x600002f81b80> (entity: Image; id: 0x600000f44fe0 <x-coredata:///Image/t8C3934D6-DCD7-4A7B-A69C-9C18334F7A942> ; data: {
    image = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 0001>;
    location = nil;
}) , destination = <Location: 0x600002fb3020> (entity: Location; id: 0xd78dad45136e9365 <x-coredata://9CA497CF-69A8-44ED-8741-C75AF480446E/Location/p2> ; data: {
    images = "<relationship fault: 0x600000f44480 'images'>";
    location = "29.977646364835238,31.32489065578125";
}))
```

I know this question was asked several times before, I've checked some of the answers but I really couldn't know what my code lacks. Here is my code:

```
func saveImagesToDb () {

            //Store the image in the DB along with its location on the background thread
            dataController.backgroundContext.perform {
                let imageOnMainContext = Image (context: self.dataController.viewContext)
                let imageManagedObjectId = imageOnMainContext.objectID
                let imageOnBackgroundContext = self.dataController.backgroundContext.object(with: imageManagedObjectId) as! Image

                for downloadedImage in self.downloadedImages {

                    let imageData = NSData (data: downloadedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!)
                    imageOnBackgroundContext.image = imageData as Data
                    imageOnBackgroundContext.location = self.imagesLocation


                    try? self.dataController.backgroundContext.save ()
                }
            }


    }
```

I just have two entities, Location and Image. The Location has an attribute called location, and Image has an attribute called image. There is a one-to-many relationship between them (one location can have many images).

I'm aware that every context preserves its own copy of `NSManagedObjects`. That's why, in the code I first got an Image based on the view context, got its id, then used that id to get an Image object on the background context.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to Core Data so I'll appreciate any help that can explain to me what's happening here and how I can solve it.

**Update**: The problem was with `imagesLocation` which was built on the view context, so I just created a corresponding object from it using its ID on the background context. After that, the problem was solved, but I also had a problem with Image object and relationship as in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004589/problems-saving-nsmanagedobjects-on-a-background-context/54016592#54016592). I could solve that and I posted the answer, you can check it.

Comment: The problem probably lies in your line which sets the location on imageOnBackgroundContext to self.imagesLocation. That imagesLocation variable probably holds an NSManagedObject on a context that is not your backgroundContext.

Comment: @FJdeBrienne Yes you're right, imagesLocation has a value of a Location that's created on the main thread. I made a Location object on the background context using the ID as I did with the Image object and it worked but I got another error about which may post another question. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and update my question? Thank you for the help

Comment: thanks, I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though `self.imagesLocation` is an NSManagedObject created on a foreign thread and, as such, cannot be assigned to the `imageOnBackgroundContext`.

You should fetch the object pointed to by `self.imagesLocation` in your `backgroundContext` using its `NSManagedObjectID` and assign that fetched object to your `imageOnBackgroundContext`