# Problems saving NSManagedObjects on a background Context

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, data-persistence

I've been struggling with this for days. I'll appreciate any help.

I have a Location `NSManagedObject` and an Image `NSManagedObject`, they have one-to-many relationship, i.e., one location has many images.

I have 2 screens, in the first one the user adds locations on the view context and they get added and retrieved without problems.

Now, in the second screen, I want to retrieve images based on the location selected in the first screen, then display the images in a Collection View. The images are first retrieved from flickr, then saved in the DB.

I want to save and retrieve images on a background context and this causes me a lot of problems.

1. When I try to save every image retrieved from flickr I get a warning stating that there is a dangling object and the relationship can' be established:

This is my saving code:

```
  func saveImagesToDb () {

        //Store the image in the DB along with its location on the background thread
        if (doesImageExist()){
            dataController.backgroundContext.perform {

                for downloadedImage in self.downloadedImages {
                    print ("saving to context")
                    let imageOnMainContext = Image (context: self.dataController.viewContext)
                    let imageManagedObjectId = imageOnMainContext.objectID
                    let imageOnBackgroundContext = self.dataController.backgroundContext.object(with: imageManagedObjectId) as! Image

                    let locationObjectId = self.imagesLocation.objectID
                    let locationOnBackgroundContext = self.dataController.backgroundContext.object(with: locationObjectId) as! Location

                    let imageData = NSData (data: downloadedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!)
                    imageOnBackgroundContext.image = imageData as Data
                    imageOnBackgroundContext.location = locationOnBackgroundContext


                    try? self.dataController.backgroundContext.save ()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the code above I'm building NSManagedObject on the background context based on the ID retrieved from those on the view context. Every time `saveImagesToDb` is called I get the warning, so what's the problem?

2. In spite of the warning above, when I retrieve the data through a FetchedResultsController (which works on the background context). The Collection View sometimes view the images just fine and sometimes I get this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`'

Here are some code snippets that are related to setting up the FetchedResultsController and updating the Collection View based on changes in the context or in the FetchedResultsController.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        guard let imagesCount = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count else {return 0}

        return imagesCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print ("cell data")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        //cell.placeImage.image = UIImage (named: "placeholder")

        let imageObject = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let imageData = imageObject.image
        let uiImage = UIImage (data: imageData!)

        cell.placeImage.image = uiImage
        return cell
    }



func setUpFetchedResultsController () {
        print ("setting up controller")
        //Build a request for the Image ManagedObject
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest <Image> = Image.fetchRequest()
        //Fetch the images only related to the images location

        let locationObjectId = self.imagesLocation.objectID
        let locationOnBackgroundContext = self.dataController.backgroundContext.object(with: locationObjectId) as! Location
        let predicate = NSPredicate (format: "location == %@", locationOnBackgroundContext)

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "location", ascending: true)]

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController (fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: dataController.backgroundContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "\(latLongString) images")

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch ()
        } catch {
            fatalError("couldn't retrive images for the selected location")
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        print ("object info changed in fecthed controller")

        switch type {
        case .insert:
            print ("insert")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print ("calling section items")
                self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
                self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
            }
            break

        case .delete:
            print ("delete")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
                self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])
            }
            break
        case .update:
            print ("update")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
                self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath!])
            }
            break
        case .move:
            print ("move")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
                self.collectionView.moveItem(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)

            }

        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        print ("section info changed in fecthed controller")
        let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
            collectionView.insertSections(indexSet)
            break
        case .delete:
            self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
            collectionView.deleteSections(indexSet)
        case .update, .move:
            fatalError("Invalid change type in controller(_:didChange:atSectionIndex:for:). Only .insert or .delete should be possible.")
        }

    }

    func addSaveNotificationObserver() {
        removeSaveNotificationObserver()
        print ("context onbserver notified")
        saveObserverToken = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: dataController?.backgroundContext, queue: nil, using: handleSaveNotification(notification:))
    }

    func removeSaveNotificationObserver() {
        if let token = saveObserverToken {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token)
        }
    }

    func handleSaveNotification(notification:Notification) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank **Robin Bork, Eugene El, and meim** for their answers.

I could finally solve both issues.

For the CollectionView problem, I felt like I was updating it too many times, as you can see in the code, I used to update it in two `FetchedResultsController` delegate methods, and also through an observer that observes any changes on the context. So I removed all of that and just used this method:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: 

    NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

In addition to that, CollectionView has a bug in maintaining the items count in a section sometimes as **Eugene El** mentioned. So, I just used reloadData to update its items and that worked well, I removed the usage of any method that adjusts its items item by item like inserting an item at a specific `IndexPath`.

For the dangling object problem. As you can see from the code, I had a Location object and an Image object. My location object was already filled with a location and it was coming from `view context`, so I just needed to create a corresponding object from it using its ID (as you see in the code in the question).

The problem was in the image object, I was creating an object on the `view context` (which contains no data inserted), get its ID, then build a corresponding object on the `background context`. After reading about this error and thinking about my code, I thought that the reason maybe because the Image object on the `view context` didn't contain any data. So, I removed the code that creates that object on the `view context` and created a one directly on the `background context` and used it as in the code below, and it worked!

```
func saveImagesToDb () {

        //Store the image in the DB along with its location on the background thread
        dataController.backgroundContext.perform {
            for downloadedImage in self.downloadedImages {
                let imageOnBackgroundContext = Image (context: self.dataController.backgroundContext)

                //imagesLocation is on the view context
                let locationObjectId = self.imagesLocation.objectID
                let locationOnBackgroundContext = self.dataController.backgroundContext.object(with: locationObjectId) as! Location

                let imageData = NSData (data: downloadedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!)
                imageOnBackgroundContext.image = imageData as Data
                imageOnBackgroundContext.location = locationOnBackgroundContext


                guard (try? self.dataController.backgroundContext.save ()) != nil else {
                    self.showAlert("Saving Error", "Couldn't store images in Database")
                    return
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

If anyone has another thought different from what I said about why the first method that first creates an empty Image object on the `view context`, then creates a corresponding one on the `background context` didn't work, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you what the problem is with 1), but I think 2) is not (just) a problem with the database.

The error your are getting usually happens when you add or remove items/sections to a collectionview, but when *numberOfItemsInSection* is called afterwards the numbers don't add up. Example: you have 5 items and add 2, but then *numberOfItemsInSection* is called and returns 6, which creates the inconsistency.

In your case my guess would be that you add items with *collectionView.insertItems()*, but this line returns 0 afterwards:

```
guard let imagesCount = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count else {return 0}
```

What also confused me in your code are these parts:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print ("calling section items")
            self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
        }
```

You are requesting the number of items there, but you don't actually do anything with the result of the function. Is there a reason for that?

Even though I don't know what the CoreData issue is I would advise you to not access the DB in the tableview delegate methods, but to have an array of items that is fetched once and is updated only when the db content changes. That is probably more performant and a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks @Robin Bork. As for the line that looks confusing, I used it based on Michael Su answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199985/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-items-on-uicollectionview. The discussion states that the problem is from a bug in Collection View as it doesn't know the number of items it has, so adding that line would let it know the count, but it seems that it's not solving the problem completely. I printed "imagesCount", for the first 3 insert operations it's always 1, suddenly it jumped to 4, after that the insert produces the crash. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Ah, that is good to know, I was not aware of this bug. Regarding your problem: It might be caused by a race condition when adding data to the DB in the background, but it's hard to say without actually trying it, so it's just a guess. My recommendation is to 1) move all the DB code out of the VC for a cleaner architecture and 2) cache the items one every change (insert/delete) to a property so that there is a central "truth" for the content of your collectionview at any given moment. Right now every callback method makes its own call to the DB and we don't know if the result is always the same

Comment: Another observation: I see that you have code for adding and removing sections in your collection view as well.  Is that being called? In your numberOfItemsInSection you make no distinction between the different sections as far as I can see that might also result to wrong counts.

Comment: thanks for the help. Yes, you're right about the section updates that wasn't needed. I could finally solve both problems, I posted an answer about that, you can check it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You have a common problem with `UICollectionView` inconsistency during batching update.
If you perform deletion/adding new items in the incorrect order `UICollectionView` might crash. 
This problem has 2 typical solutions:

1. use -reloadData() instead of batch updates.
2. use third party libraries with safe implementation of batch update. Smth like this https://github.com/badoo/ios-collection-batch-updates

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NSFetchedResultsController should only use a **main thread** NSManagedObjectContext.

**Solution**: create two NSManagedObjectContext objects, one in the main thread for NSFetchedResultsController and one in the background thread for performing the data writing.

`let writeContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
let readContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
let fetchedController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: readContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
writeContext.parent = readContext`

UICollectionView will be updated properly once the data is saved in the **writeContext** with the following chain:

> writeContext(background thread ) -> readContext(main thread) -> NSFetchedResultsController (main thread) -> UICollectionView (main thread)